# Identifying when logstash jdbc SQL statement has completed execution

Tags: logstash, logstash-jdbc

I've set up a logstash pipeline watching a directory for `logstash.conf`s with a jdbc input and elasticsearch output.

I enabled `.logstash_jdbc_test_last_run`, which logs the time when query is executed:

```
--- 2019-08-23 15:26:42.847349000 Z
```

When running logstash on the command line, my pipeline successfully processes a logstash conf file:

```
[2019-08-23T15:26:48,168][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (5.250782s) select S0.* from mytable S0
```

I'm trying to have my application notified that logstash has finished processing a logstash conf and the data is available in ES. Is there a way to write the timestamp when the query has completed to a file (for use as a flag in my application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I was able to get the desired result by leveraging multiple pipelines
Thanks @apt-get_install_skill, you led me down the right path!

`pipelines.yml`:

```
- pipeline.id: logstash
  pipeline.workers: 1
  path.config: "/tmp/logstash*.conf"
  queue.type: persisted
- pipeline.id: postprocessing
  pipeline.workers: 1
  path.config: "/tmp/postprocessing*.conf"
```

`logstash.conf`:

```
input {
   jdbc {
     ...
   }
}
output   {
    elasticsearch {
      ...
    }
    pipeline { send_to => [postProcessing] }
}
```

`postprocessing.conf`, which uses the output from the `logstash` pipeline:

```
input {
    pipeline { address => postProcessing }
}
output {
    file{
        path => "/tmp/finishedflag"
        codec => "dots"
    }
}
```

Codec `dots` as I don't care about the data itself.

When it runs, it will first run the `logstash` pipeline, and when it completes it runs the `postprocessing` pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware that Logstash logs the timestamp when it has actually **completed** an SQL query. What you can do anyway is to implement an additional pipeline where you read the .logstash_jdbc_test_last_run file. From my experience, Logstash will **not** update the timestamp until it has fetched all records.

So this pipeline would look something like that (untested):

```
input{
  file{
    path => ["/your/absolute/path/to/.logstash_jdbc_test_last_run"]
    file_completed_action => "log"
    file_completed_log_path => "/path/where/logfile/should/be/stored"
    mode => "read"
    codec => "plain" # default, you could do json as well
  }
}
output{
  file{
    path => "/foo/bar/logstash_runs.txt"
  }
}
```

This pipeline would recognize every new/updated timestamp of the file and append it to the specified file you configured in the output plugin.

Take a look at the [file input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html) as well as the [file output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-file.html) for all configuration settings.